# Tilde character on Mavericks/Macbook air with Norwegian keyboard turns into >

Tags: macos, keyboard, macbook-pro, internationalization

After upgrading my MB Air & upgrading to Mavericks, I can't get my beloved tilde character to turn up. I got a Norwegian keyboard, so there is no dedicated tilde character.

Answers from Google and search here has so far not solved the problem for me.

I tried using KeyRemap4MacBook with option Shift+Escape to tilde, which gives me the > character.

This fits what has been mentioned elsewhere: That the tilde on the international keyboard is between left Shift and the Z key - which on mine is >

Is there something obvious i'm missing?

Comment: On a Mac Norwegian keyboard the tilde is not on the key next to Z.  That has > and < .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the Apple Norwegian layout, tilde should be at option plus ¨, then space.

On the Apple Norwegian Extended layout, tilde should be at option plus k, then space.

Comment: I was using Norwegian Extended keyboard layout, and you're totally right!

Answer (score 2):

If you switch to the non "extended" keyboard layout (doing this does not mean that the numpad stops working) then you can use the much simpler key combination Alt+^ to make a ~ character

#### How to do this:

Open **System Preferences** -> **Keyboard** -> **Input Sources** -> find **Norwegian Bokmål** in the list -> select **Norwegian**

When you have done this I would urge you to delete the "Norwegian Extended" keyboard so you are sure what keyboard you are using. You can just re-add it using the recipe above if you change your mind.

Comment: Kindly add a little more details on how to "switch to the non "extended" keyboard layout" for clarity.

Comment: @perhapsmaybeharry Hope the extra info helps you along

Answer (score 1):

On my Macbook Pro with a Norwegian Extended keyboard I press <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>, and then I press <kbd>Space</kbd>