# How to output tilde (~) directly

Tags: keyboard, input-source

I would like to be able to type the character `~` directly, without having to follow up with a `space`.

Currently, if I type the tilde character, at first I get a `˜`, which becomes a `~` only if I follow it up with a `space`.

The same question extends to `'`, `"` and `, but I presume the solution is the same for all of them.

I am using a M1 Macbook Air, with a "U.S. International PC" keyboard layout.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the actual keyboard? Apple don't make a 'PC keyboard' of any sort. Is it an external? If so, please post a photo of it. It's important to know whether the layout is ISO or ANSI.

Comment: @Tetsujin. The keyboard in the picture is the one called English International by Apple. I don't think they make separate one for Brazil.

Comment: That's just an International English keyboard, common in Europe. Tom's answer solved my issue.

Comment: Ah, yes. The # and $ threw me ;) I'm used to UK English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get rid of the "US International PC" layout and instead use "US" or "ABC".  You do this in system preferences > keyboard > input sources.

(US International PC is a special layout adopted from Windows which is intended to make it easy to write the accents needed in common European languages.)

Comment: This was much simpler than I've anticipated... Thanks ~~~~~~

Comment: Different international keyboards also have distinct ways to produce this. [Italian layout](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/60943/5472) and [Spanish layout](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/219603/5472) and [German layout](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/395677/5472) and [Norwegian layout](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/141066/5472) and [Swedish layout](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/329085/5472)

Comment: This doesn't work for MacBook Pro 2021 with [ISO - International English Layout](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102743) in macOS Sonoma 14.1.1
Both ABC and English U.S. share the same keyboard layout where tilde is place left to the 'z'

Comment: @laertis   That is exactly where tilde is supposed to be on the International English keyboard.  Do you not produce ~ when you press Shift on that key?  If not, what does it produce?

Comment: You are correct! I was in a search spree on how to switch ~ with ± characters since I'm coming from an ANSI keyboard that I didn't even read the whole question. Please disregard my answer.